# Upload file to API endpoint Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to upload files via API, in POSTMAN I can do it perfectly. However when doing in my application is not accepted.

Store in Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'projeto_id' => 'required|integer',
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'logo'  => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2000',
        'telephone' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'desc' => 'required|string',
        'quantity' => 'required|integer|gt:0|lt:51',
        'sequential' => 'required|integer|gt:0',
    ]);
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    if($user != Auth::id()){
        abort(403);
    }

    //UPLOAD IMAGEM DO GRUPO
    $logo = $request['logo'];  
    // Check if a profile image has been uploaded
    if ($request->has('logo')) {
        // Get image file
        $image = $request->file('logo');
        // Make a image name based on user name and current timestamp
        $name = Str::slug($user.'_'.time());
        // Define folder path
        $folder = '/uploads/images/'.$user.'/groupimg/logo/';
        // Make a file path where image will be stored [ folder path + file name + file extension]
        $filePath = $folder . $name. '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Upload image
        $this->uploadOne($image, $folder, 'public', $name);
        // Set user profile image path in database to filePath
        $logo = $filePath;
    
    }

    $gPrivado = '0';
    if($request->has('private')){
        $gPrivado = '1';
    }
    $i = 0;
    $delayCounter = 0;
    $sequential = $data['sequential'];
    while ($i < (int)$data['quantity']) {
        $delay = $delayCounter + rand(10, 15);
        CreateGroups::dispatch($data['name'] . " {$sequential}", $logo , $data['desc'], $gPrivado, [$data['telephone']], $data['projeto_id'], auth()->user())
            ->delay(Carbon::now()
                ->addSeconds($delay));
        $delayCounter = $delay;
        $i++;
        $sequential++;
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Grupos adicionados em fila de criação, aguarde alguns minutos .');
}
```

Use Job to proccess:

```
public function handle()
{
    $user = $this->user;
    if ($user->instance_connected) {
        $ZApi = new ZApi($user->zapi_instance_id, $user->zapi_token);
        $createdGroup = $ZApi
            ->createGroup($this->name, $this->phones);
            sleep(3);
            foreach($createdGroup->groupInfo as $informacoes){
        $linkInvite = $ZApi->getGroupInvite($informacoes->id);
        $idGroup = $informacoes->id;
            }
        //DESCRICAO DO GRUPO
        $descricao = $this->desc;
        $setDescricao = $ZApi->setGroupDescription($idGroup, $descricao);

        //GRUPO PRIVADO
        if ($this->private == '1'){
            $grupoPrivado = $ZApi->setGroupMessages($idGroup, 'true');
            $adminOnly =  $ZApi->setGroupEdit($idGroup, 'true');
        }
$setImg =  $ZApi->groupImage($idGroup, $this->logo);
```

The last line send to API, I'm using Guzzle

And this is my API function

```
public function groupImage(string $groupId, string $value)
 {
     return $this->doRequest2('POST', "group-pic", [
        'multipart' => [
            [                    
                'name' => 'phone',
                'contents' => $groupId,                    
            ],
            [
                'Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                'name' => 'file',
                'contents' => fopen('storage'.$value, 'r'),
            ]
         
           ]
         
     ]);
 }
```

But get this error response

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException Client error: `POST http://localhost:8081/api/danilo/group-pic` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"status":"Error","message":"File parameter is
> required!"}

Can someone help me?

Comment: This does look like an Error from your code, not Laravel (maybe `uploadOne`?). Laravel Validation errors would be structured as `{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{` with code 422. Maybe you should set a `filename` in the file-upload multipart element too.